# How are Rust Traits different from Go Interfaces?

Tags: go, rust

I am relatively familiar with Go, having written a number of small programs in it. Rust, of course, I am less familiar with but keeping an eye on.

Having recently read http://yager.io/programming/go.html, I thought I'd personally examine the two ways Generics are handled because the article seemed to unfairly criticize Go when, in practice, there wasn't much that Interfaces couldn't accomplish elegantly. I kept hearing the hype about how powerful Rust's Traits were and nothing but criticism from people about Go. Having some experience in Go, I wondered how true it was and what the differences ultimately were. What I found was that Traits and Interfaces are pretty similar! Ultimately, I'm not sure if I'm missing something, so here is a quick educational rundown of their similarities so you can tell me what I missed!

Now, let's take a look at Go Interfaces from their [documentation](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces):

> Interfaces in Go provide a way to specify the behavior of an object: if something can do this, then it can be used here.

By far the most common interface is `Stringer` which returns a string representing the object.

```
type Stringer interface {
    String() string
}
```

So, any object that has `String()` defined on it is a `Stringer` object. This can be used in type signatures such that `func (s Stringer) print()` takes almost all objects and prints them.

We also have `interface{}` which takes any object. We must then determine the type at runtime through reflection.

---

Now, let's take a look at Rust Traits from their [documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/tutorial.html#traits):

> At its simplest, a trait is a set of zero or more method signatures. For example, we could declare the trait Printable for things that can be printed to the console, with a single method signature:

```
trait Printable {
    fn print(&self);
}
```

This immediately looks quite similar to our Go Interfaces. The only difference I see is that we define 'Implementations' of Traits rather than just defining the methods. So, we do

```
impl Printable for int {
    fn print(&self) { println!("{}", *self) }
}
```

instead of

```
fn print(a: int) { ... }
```

**Bonus Question:** What happens in Rust if you define a function that implements a trait but you don't use `impl`? It just doesn't work?

Unlike Go's Interfaces, Rust's type system has type parameters which let you do proper generics and things like `interface{}` while the compiler and the runtime actually know the type. For example,

```
trait Seq<T> {
    fn length(&self) -> uint;
}
```

works on any type and the compiler *knows* that the type of the Sequence elements at compile time rather than using reflection.

---

Now, the actual question: am I missing any differences here? Are they really *that* similar? Is there not some more fundamental difference that I'm missing here? (In usage. Implementation details are interesting, but ultimately not important if they function the same.)

Besides syntactic differences, the actual differences I see are:

1. Go has automatic method dispatch vs. Rust requires(?) `impl`s to implement a Trait

   - Elegant vs. Explicit
2. Rust has type parameters which allow for proper generics without reflection.

   - Go really has no response here. This is the only thing that is significantly more powerful and it's ultimately just a replacement for copying and pasting methods with different type signatures.

Are these the only non-trivial differences? If so, it would appear Go's Interface/Type system is, in practice, not as weak as perceived.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

> What happens in Rust if you define a function that implements a trait but you don't use impl? It just doesn't work?

You need to explicitly implement the trait; happening to have a method with matching name/signature is meaningless for Rust.

## Generic call dispatching

> Are these the only non-trivial differences? If so, it would appear Go's Interface/Type system is, in practice, not as weak as perceived.

Not providing static dispatch can be a significant performance hit for certain cases (e.g. the `Iterator` one I mention below). I think this is what you mean by

> Go really has no response here. This is the only thing that is significantly more powerful and it's ultimately just a replacement for copying and pasting methods with different type signatures.

but I'll cover it in more detail, because it's worth understanding the difference deeply.

### In Rust

Rust's approach allows for the user to choose between static dispatch and [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). As an example,  if you have

```rust
trait Foo { fn bar(&self); }

impl Foo for int { fn bar(&self) {} }
impl Foo for String { fn bar(&self) {} }

fn call_bar<T: Foo>(value: T) { value.bar() }

fn main() {
    call_bar(1i);
    call_bar("foo".to_string());
}
```

then the two `call_bar` calls above will compile to calls to, respectively,

```rust
fn call_bar_int(value: int) { value.bar() }
fn call_bar_string(value: String) { value.bar() }
```

where those `.bar()` method calls are static function calls, i.e. to a fixed function address in memory. This allows for optimisations like inlining, because the compiler knows *exactly* which function is being called. (This is what C++ does too, sometimes called "monomorphisation".)

### In Go

Go only allows dynamic dispatch for "generic" functions, that is, the method address is loaded from the value and then called from there, so the exact function is only known at runtime. Using the example above

```golang
type Foo interface { bar() }

func call_bar(value Foo) { value.bar() }

type X int;
type Y string;
func (X) bar() {}
func (Y) bar() {}

func main() {
    call_bar(X(1))
    call_bar(Y("foo"))
}
```

Now, those two `call_bar`s will always be calling the above `call_bar`, with the address of `bar` loaded from the interface's [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

### Low-level

To rephrase the above, in C notation. Rust's version creates

```rust
/* "implementing" the trait */
void bar_int(...) { ... }
void bar_string(...) { ... }

/* the monomorphised `call_bar` function */
void call_bar_int(int value) {
    bar_int(value);
}
void call_bar_string(string value) {
    bar_string(value);
}

int main() {
    call_bar_int(1);
    call_bar_string("foo");
    // pretend that is the (hypothetical) `string` type, not a `char*`
    return 1;
}
```

For Go, it's something more like:

```golang
/* implementing the interface */
void bar_int(...) { ... }
void bar_string(...) { ... }

// the Foo interface type
struct Foo {
    void* data;
    struct FooVTable* vtable;
}
struct FooVTable {
    void (*bar)(void*);
}

void call_bar(struct Foo value) {
    value.vtable.bar(value.data);
}

static struct FooVTable int_vtable = { bar_int };
static struct FooVTable string_vtable = { bar_string };

int main() {
    int* i = malloc(sizeof *i);
    *i = 1;
    struct Foo int_data = { i, &int_vtable };
    call_bar(int_data);

    string* s = malloc(sizeof *s);
    *s = "foo"; // again, pretend the types work
    struct Foo string_data = { s, &string_vtable };
    call_bar(string_data);
}
```

(This isn't exactly right---there has to be more information in the vtable---but the method call being a dynamic function pointer is the relevant thing here.)

### Rust offers the choice

Going back to

> Rust's approach allows for the user to choose between static dispatch and dynamic dispatch.

So far I've only demonstrated Rust having statically dispatched generics, but Rust can opt-in to the dynamic ones like Go (with essentially the same implementation), via trait objects. Notated like `&Foo`, which is a borrowed reference to an unknown type that implements the `Foo` trait. These values have the same/very similar vtable representation to the Go interface object. (A trait object is an example of an ["existential type"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type).)

There are instances where dynamic dispatch is really helpful (and sometimes more performant, by, e.g. reducing code bloat/duplication), but static dispatch allows compilers to inline the callsites and apply all their optimisations, meaning it is normally faster. This is especially important for things like [Rust's iteration protocol](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html), where static dispatching trait method calls allows for those iterators to be as fast as the C equivalents, while still [seeming high-level and expressive](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2014/06/error-handling-in-rust-knn-case-study/).

Tl;dr: Rust's approach offers both static and dynamic dispatch in generics, at the programmers discretion; Go only allows for dynamic dispatch.

## Parametric polymorphism

Furthermore, emphasising traits and deemphasising reflection gives Rust much stronger [parametric polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism): the programmer knows exactly what a function can do with its arguments, because it has to declare the traits the generic types implement in the function signature.

Go's approach is very flexible, but has fewer guarantees for the callers (making it somewhat harder for the programmer to reason about), because the internals of a function can (and do) query for additional type information (there was a bug in the Go standard library where, iirc, a function taking a writer would use reflection to call `Flush` on some inputs, but not others).

## Building abstractions

This is somewhat of a sore point, so I'll only talk briefly, but having "proper" generics like Rust has allows for low level data types like Go's `map` and `[]` to actually be implemented directly in the standard library in a strongly typesafe way, and written in Rust ([`HashMap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/collections/hashmap/struct.HashMap.html) and [`Vec`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) respectively).

And its not just those types, you can build type-safe generic structures on top of them, e.g. [`LruCache`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/collections/lru_cache/struct.LruCache.html) is a generic caching layer on top of a hashmap. This means people can just use the data structures directly from the standard library, *without* having to store data as `interface{}` and use type assertions when inserting/extracting. That is, if you have an `LruCache<int, String>`, you're guaranteed that the keys are always `int`s and the values are always `String`s: there's no way to accidentally insert the wrong value (or try to extract a non-`String`).

Comment: As I expected, Rust is more powerful and offers more choice natively/elegantly, but Go's system is close enough that most things it misses can be accomplished with small hacks like `interface{}`. While Rust seems technically superior, I still think the criticism of Go... has been a bit too harsh. The power of the programmer is pretty much on par for 99% of tasks.

Comment: @Logan, for the low-level/high-performance domains Rust is aiming for (e.g. operating systems, web browsers... the core "systems" programming stuff), not having the option of static dispatch (and performance it gives/optimisation it allows) is unacceptable. It is one of the reasons that Go isn't as suitable as Rust for those sort of applications. In any case, the power of the programmer isn't really on par, you lose (compile time) type safety for any reusable and non-built-in data structure, falling back to runtime type assertions.

Comment: That's exactly right--Rust offers you a lot more power. I think of Rust as a safe C++, and Go as a fast Python (or a vastly simplified Java). For the large percentage of tasks where developer productivity matters most (and things like runtimes and garbage collection aren't problematic), choose Go (e.g., web servers, concurrent systems, command line utilities, user applications, etc). If you need every last bit of performance (and developer productivity be damned), choose Rust (e.g., browsers, operating systems, resource-constrained embedded systems).